# INPUT_VALIDATION_ERROR in BetFair Login API / iOS

Tags: ios, swift, betfair

I am getting INPUT_VALIDATION_ERROR while logging into betfair api. I am following the docs, but it was of no use with this particular error code.

I'd appreciate if anyone could guide me in the right direction.

Here is my swift code

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://identitysso.betfair.com/api/login")!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"


                request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue("MY_APP_KEY", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Application")


        let postString = "username=MY_USER_NAME&password=MY_PASSWORD"
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }
        task.resume()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set header in http for `Content-Type` as

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Three parameters in Http header:

```
    httpRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpRequest.setHeader("X-Application", <apiKey>);
```